# Extra space between menu and the vertical navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm writing website using bootstrap and I got extra space between vertical navigation bar and my site's menu. It's like +/- 10 px on large screen but there is a horizontal bar because of that. 
My code:

```
<header>
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <a href="logo"><img src="logo.png" width="100%"/></a>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu col-sm-12">         
            <li><a href="start"><i class="icon-users"></i>  About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="out-products"><i class="icon-leanpub"></i>  Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact"><i class="icon-mail-alt"></i>  Contact</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</header>
```

and `.menu` class in CSS:

```css
.menu
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 150%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(165,160,160,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

[image: menu]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: can you post output?

Comment: Of course [link](https://imgur.com/a/NnWprFJ)

Comment: use this, width:100%

Comment: I tried width: 100% and it doesn't help

Comment: also try for header tag

Comment: I did this website in html+css earlier and width: 100% helped me to get expected layout. Now I'm writing it using html+css+bootstrap and all of the possible combinations of adding "width: 100%" to header tag or/and to .menu don't work

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your HTML, columns should be in rows like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <p> My content </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <p> My other content </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your problem could be fixed if you remove padding-top from .menu or set it to 0

```
.menu
    {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 0; // do not add padding to top
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 150%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(165,160,160,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I meant deleting this space [link](https://imgur.com/rsR3S5s) and padding-top does nothing with it